# WebClient and request headers

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest, webclient

Consider the following function :

```
    public string Get(string url, string parameters = "", bool xml = false)
    {
        try
        {
            if(xml) { client.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
            return client.DownloadString(url + "?" + parameters);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

and the two calls to it:

```
Get("http://www.host.com", "", true);
Get("http://www.host.com", "", false);
```

Will the second Get() call have the X-Requested-With header set? Do these headers get 'resetted' after each call to WebClient.DownloadString functions or I have to manually revert them back to their default values ?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if I inserted a breakpoint on the `return ...` line and examined `client.Headers`. I will refrain from downvoting, but please consider answering your own question below.

Comment: It's possible he's running code in an environment where he can't use a debugger, such as an ASP.NET Website using runtime-compiled code.

Comment: @Ahmed Why do you want to call two Get with different bool's

Comment: @David: That doesn't stop the OP from trying it in a separate command-line project. You don't have to perform experiments in your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the code, I came to the conclusion that the set headers persist and that they need to be reverted back to the default values manually in this case.

Comment: Do you want an upvote for what you should have already done before asking here ?

Comment: Reading the documentation would provide a similar result.